# Use a shared library with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have a C++ project compiled in a shared library. I need to use that library (.so file) in Android with the NDK.

The idea is that someone else would compile the C++ project and give me the .so file, so that I don't have to compile it on my computer.

I need to reference the .so file in my Android.mk file, and all the solutions I tried did not work. That's where I'm stuck.

So:

- is it possible to do what I described without creating one shared library per platform?
- how can I reference my .so library in my Android.mk? All the solutions I tried did not work.

---

To reproduce everything from scratch, I did these steps:

1°) Create a HelloWorld C++ project:

- Test.h:

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  class Test {

      public:

      Test();
      ~Test();

      static std::string getTest();
  };
  ```
- Test.cpp:

  ```
  #include "Test.h"

  std::string Test::getTest()
  {
      return "Hey!!\n";
  }
  ```

2°) Create the shared library:

```
g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libTest.so Test.cpp
```

This gaves me a libTest.so file, which I can use on a C++ project. Now I want to use it on an Android project.

3°) Create a basic empty Android project:

- package: com.so.test
- name: CppTest

4°) Create a "Test.java" file next to the MainActivity.java file containing:

```
package com.so.test;

public class Test {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hellondk");
    }

    public native String getMessage();
}
```

5°) Open a terminal and:

```
cd /path/to/my/android/project/app/src/main/java
javac com/so/test/Test.java
javah com.so.test.Test
```

This creates the "com_so_test_Test.h" file.

```
cd /path/to/my/android/project
mkdir jni
mv app/src/main/java/com_so_test_Test.h jni
touch jni/com_so_test_Test.cpp
```

6°) Add the following code in "com_so_test_Test.cpp" file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "com_so_test_Test.h"
#include "Test.hpp"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_so_test_Test_getMessage(JNIEnv* env, jobject ob)
{
    return env->NewStringUTF(Test::getTest().c_str());
}
```

7°) Copy "Test.h" and "libTest.so" files created on steps 1 & 2 into "jni" folder

8°) Create an "Android.mk" file in the "jni" folder containing:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := hellondk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_so_test_Test.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

9°) Create an "Application.mk" file in the "jni" folder containing:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

10°) Back in the terminal, run:

```
/path/to/your/ndk/ndk-build
```

And that's the step where I'm stuck. I need to reference the libTest.so file in the Android.mk, but all the solutions I tried did not work. Any idea?

EDIT: here is the error I get:

```
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : hellondk <= com_so_test_Test.cpp
[arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libhellondk.so
./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/hellondk/com_so_test_Test.o: In function `Java_com_so_test_Test_getMessage':
/Users/timsandra/Desktop/CppTest/jni/com_so_test_Test.cpp:8: undefined reference to `Test::getTest()'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/libhellondk.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Probably too late, but from the error message, looks like a simple typo? (6) `#include "Test.hpp"` should be `#include "Test.h"`. Your question was so complete, I used it as a reference to get my first android jni call running ever - thanks buddy!

Comment: The problems begin at step 2°. You compiled Test.cpp for your PC. You must cross-compile it for Android, using NDK.